# How to efficient search elements

Tags: scala

I have a collection of

```
case class User(id: Int, parentId: Int)

val users = Seq(User(3, 23), User(4, 17), User(22, 23),User(29, 90))
```

I need do efficient (less than O(n)) search by "parentId":

```
val testUser = User(23, 999)

val found = users.filter(u => u.parentId == testUser.id)

res: List(User(3,23), User(22,23))
```

How I can achive this and which data structure to use?

Comment: You'll have to use a better data structure for the purpose. The `Seq` constructor gives you a (immutable) linked list. With linked lists, the best you're going to get is `O(n)`.

Comment: If your data has been sorted (`users.sortBy(_.parentId)`) then you could do a binary search. If it's in random order then O(n) is what you get.

Comment: @jwvh provides an interesting option, but of course the sort is also a O(n * log(n)) step, and the binary search would be an additional O(log(n)), so the groupBy solution below is a better choice if you are going to pre-process the data. Also, a binary search would be very inefficient on `List` because it uses a linked-list implementation and so doesn't support O(1) random access, so you would also want to use a `Vector` or other `IndexedSeq` instead if you were going to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use groupBy to convert your Seq to a Map, which will give you O(1) lookup:

```
case class User(id: Int, parentId: Int)

val users = Seq(User(3, 23), User(4, 17), User(22, 23),User(29, 90))

val usersMap = users.groupBy(_.parentId)

val testUser = User(23, 999)

val found = usersMap.get(testUser.id)
```

Comment: I think we should also note the complexity to convert to Map using groupBy if possible (which I would assume to be O(n))

Comment: @JordanCutler Yeah, you have a point. My guess would also be O(n), but this would only happen once. All subsequent lookups will then be constant time.